# Apple Smart Banner (meta apple-itunes-app) not working with my app ID - also not after clearing cache on iPhone Safari

Tags: ios, itunes, meta-tags, smartbanner

Apple Smart Banner (meta apple-itunes-app) not working with my app ID - also not after clearing cache on iPhone Safari.
I'm using this:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=632225412">
```

It works if I replace the app ID with anyone else.

It used to work awhile ago, and I'm not sure what changed. Perhaps something with iOS7?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 there is a bug that prevents the banner from re-appearing. It's rather drastic, but doing a Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings seems to allow it to re-appear.